# How to display magnitude (value) of each bar in Google Image URL chart

Tags: node.js, charts, google-visualization, visualization

I am using the Google image chart API to create an image URL dynamically, to embed the URL into the Node.js Bot card.

The parameters passed to create the image bar chart URL is as follows:

```
cht=bvg
chxt=x,y
chs=150x150
chd=t:7.65,100
chl=NY
    CA
chco=FF0000
00FF00
```

The generated bar chart URL is as follows:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,y&chs=150x150&chd=t:7.65,100&chl=NY|CA&chco=FF0000|00FF00
```

**How to display the magnitude (value) of each bar in the Google chart image using the URL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [Shape Markers `chm`](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#gcharts_shape_markers)

like `chm=N,000000,0,,10`

```html
<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,y&chs=150x150&chd=t:7.65,100&chl=NY|CA&chco=FF0000|00FF00&chm=N,000000,0,,10
" />
```